# Parse Apache Thrift file

Tags: parsing, thrift

I have a huge Apache thrift file, which I need to parse and store information as per my application.

I could do this manually, reading line by line.

But it is always prone to errors and what not. So is there some API etc that I can use to parse the file fast and efficiently?

If not, any other suggestions?

Comment: There are some tools around that are able to consume Thrift IDL, like Finagle and others. I personally never dealt with any of those so far, so no guarantees here. The other way is to use the Thrift compiler code itself and write a custom generator for whatever you plan to do. It may help to know a bit more about the latter to give a more focused answer. Alas, SO is the wrong place for such kind of questions. You may ask on the mailing lists, it is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will keep in mind you suggestion the next time. :-)

Answer (score 3):

thrift cli can help you, you can generate json from thrift file, and then parse json to get struct of thrift file

```sh
thrift --gen json example.thrift
```

Answer (score 2):

Facebook's Swift tool has a Thrift IDL parser implemented in Java if that fits into your project: https://github.com/facebook/swift/tree/master/swift-idl-parser.  If your application is .NET, you might still be able to use this library if you can translate the parser JAR using IKVM.NET.  There is an ANTLR grammar in there someplace too if you want to develop your own parser.

Alternatively, I noticed that the thrift trunk now has a JSON generator that outputs the IDL as a JSON data structure, which should be easy enough to parse in any language.  You'll probably need to compile from source in order to use that generator, but Thrift picks up new features so fast that you might want to do that anyways if you are not already.